# When i create list manually in javascript, cant get the values using querySelectorAll();

Tags: javascript, list, typescript, nodes

```
  let List = document.createElement("div");
        List.setAttribute('id', 'name');
        let List1 = document.createElement("ul");
         let List2 = document.createElement("li");
            let  Value = document.createTextNode("america");
            List2.appendChild(Value);
         let List3 = document.createElement("li");
                 Value = document.createTextNode("london");
            List3.appendChild(Value);
            List1.appendChild(List2);
            List1.appendChild(List3);
            List.appendChild(List1);
```

> When i enter **let li = document.querySelectorAll("#name li");**

I didnt get list element with **li** tag?? whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the `List` node that you have created to the document.
Try this:

```
let List = document.createElement("div");
List.setAttribute('id', 'test');
let List1 = document.createElement("ul");
let List2 = document.createElement("li");
let  Value = document.createTextNode("java");
List2.appendChild(Value);
let List3 = document.createElement("li");
Value = document.createTextNode("ajax");
List3.appendChild(Value);
List1.appendChild(List2);
List1.appendChild(List3);
List.appendChild(List1);

document.body.appendChild(List);
```

Now your document.querySelectorAll statement should work.

Comment: Its throwing **TypeError: document.body.append is not a function(…)** @NahushFarkande

Comment: **appendChild** is working.. thank you !! @NahushFarkande

Comment: Right!. my mistake. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

That call would otherwise be:

```
List.querySelectorAll("#name li");
//better more  
List.querySelectorAll("li");
//because you already have the handle for #name element in your hands.
```

Regardless of the fact if they are, or not already appended to the document - you will get the elements of the query.

Never call for document Element on query selectors in case you already have the root node of your query subjects already at hand. Or if there's a local wrapper unique ID already available.

That's Costly!

You should avoid that at all times.

Never use query selector all unless there are no other alternatives.

```
List.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

is always a more preferable way to go - and blazingly faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you haven't actually added `List` to the document.